# Make Smarty ignore white space up to the next statement

Tags: html, smarty, template-engine

In a Smarty template, is there a way to make Smarty ignore white space between two statements in a logically structured code with lots of indentations, so that the resulting HTML wouldn't contain it? A practical usage would be to avoid white space between two links, since links that go in a chain would be displayed differently depending on the presence of white space in between them. I would imagine it like this:

```
<a href="">A link</a>{ignore_whitespace_up_to_next_statement_please}
{if $var == "something"}{ignore_whitespace_up_to_next_statement_please}
  <a href="">Another link</a>
{/if}
```

which would produce this HTML output:

```
<a href="">A link</a><a href="">Another link</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is the [{strip}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.strip.tpl) block you could use. Otherwise I'd suggest using the outputfilter [trimwhitespace](http://code.google.com/p/smarty-php/source/browse/trunk/distribution/libs/plugins/outputfilter.trimwhitespace.php) (or a derivation of it).